# Display all records (including null) without going through all records

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this sql query:

```
select "Amount",
    "Month",
    SCWM.out_menu1Text
from
(select sum(II2.LocalTAmountWithoutVAT) as "Amount",
    ib_string_right('00' || ib_decodedate_month(II.docdate$date), 2) as "Month",
    sc.id as "Menu"
from IssuedInvoices2 II2
join IssuedInvoices II on II.id = II2.parent_id
left join StoreCards SC on SC.ID = II2.StoreCard_ID
left join firms F on F.id = II.firm_id
where
    ib_decodedate_year(II.docdate$date) = (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE))
    and ib_decodedate_month(II.docdate$date) >= @{_od}
    and ib_decodedate_month(II.docdate$date) <= @{_do}
    and F.id = '@{_firmID}'
group by
    ib_string_right('00' || ib_decodedate_month(II.docdate$date), 2),
    "Menu")
left join ABI_StoreCardsWithMenu("Menu") SCWM on SCWM.OUT_StoreCard_ID = "Menu"
order by
    SCWM.out_menu1Text
```

with this result:

[image: Result table]

But I need to achieve this:

[Wanted table http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9486/mjw7.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9486/mjw7.png)

Function `ABI_StoreCardsWithMenu("Menu") SCWM` takes column "Menu" and return right group. For example in database is "nail" and this function takes ID of "nail" and return name of group --> "01. Potrubí a fitinky".

Reason why get so short table is, that SQL query use condition in WHERE clause. If seleceted firm haven't no `sc.id`which belongs to second group "02. Nářadí", then group will not appear in result table.

What I need is solution, which display all groups, but I need to avoid to reading of every records in database (database is so huge, that loading all record takes 10-20 minutes).

Comment: Your question title doesn't really your actual question, and I am having trouble understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: I rewrote my question. Now it's better interpretion of my problem, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a list of all the items and then `LEFT JOIN` your current query (with some modifications) to it.

For example say you have a table `ITEMS` with all the item names (instead of a table this could also be a (sub)query, view or selectable procedure), and a table `NUMBEROFITEMS` containing the count of items (again this can also be a (sub)query, view or selectable procedure).

Say `ITEMS` contains:

```
{ { ID=1, NAME='Item 1'}, { ID=2, NAME='Item 2'} }
```

And `NUMBEROFITEMS`:

```
{ { ITEMID=1, ITEMCOUNT=35 } }
```

You can then use the following query to produce the full list:

```
SELECT
    i.NAME,
    COALESCE(ni.ITEMCOUNT, 0)
FROM ITEMS i
LEFT JOIN NUMBEROFITEMS ni ON ni.ITEMID = i.ID
```

You just need to expand this to your specific query.